# I have code from my previous startup that my current employer needs - they want me to open source it

Tags: professionalism, united-states, software-development, software

When I left my last corporate job, I started working on my own open source project. It was sort of a 'I can do it better/learning project'. I continued to work on it and even managed to score really highly on a few Kaggle competitions using it. Which proved that I had written something valuable.

About 2 years ago, I founded a startup with someone I met on LinkedIn. Based on previous work that I had done during my PhD and folding that work into my library, I managed to successfully get a grant for 250k. Enough for the initial launch. My cofounder forced me out after I refused to use the funds for a pivot idea he had, instead insisting that we give the money back if we can't deliver what the grant was intended for. He then subsequently sued me for ownership of everything but the judge ruled that since my cofounder had never contributed a single line of code and that the code base existed before I founded the startup and since I never took a salary or vested any shares, the company had zero rights to my code. Surprise, Surprise the company went under a year later after going through 2 different CTOs.

I joined a rival startup with people I get along with better. We started discussing my library and it turns out to be exactly what the company needs. It would save them about a year of development effort. I told them that they can make me an offer but my new employers are insisting that it would be best if I open source my library and let them fork it.

While I have discussed open sourcing a core part of it (open-core)and even trying to write a book on top - I feel like this is just taking advantage of me. What do I gain in this situation? Plus I am worried about copyright, presumably any additions I make to the fork will belong to the company.

Does anyone have any advice for me. Have you ever made software that your employer was interested in? Did you sell it or let them use it?

Comment: You need a laywyer, you know this, you've been through a lawsuit before.

Comment: "I feel like this is just taking advantage of me" - well. yeah ... unless there's more to the story so do I. It's your IP - you decide what it's worth to you. Maybe it's worth money. Maybe it's worth "goodwill". Maybe something else. But it's your decision to make - not ours.

Comment: Software has a limited "shelf life." After a few years, it will need to be rewritten anyway.

Comment: @DavidR That's not how software works. Rewriting code is also [one of the worst mistakes to make](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/). It took out Netscape. It took out Borland. Microsoft did it, but kept the old code's project in parallel and actually used the old code.

Comment: They don’t want to pay you for your work.  That may happen again.

Comment: @Nelson You are correct - for software that has been proven in the marketplace. However, for a startup, the probability is high that the software will need to be redesigned, possibly several times, and rewritten several times before it is proven in the market.

Comment: "[...] but my new employers are insisting that it would be best if I open source my library [...]" - yeah, of course it would be best. *For them*.

Answer (score 16):

Nope.  Just nope.

That library is YOUR property.  Noncommercial use is one thing.  Commercial use, in which they want to get it for free and take it private, is something very different.

If you had not written your library in the first place, they would be faced with the prospect of writing it from scratch, with the accompanying costs and delays.  They should jump at the chance to pay you a fraction of the development cost for a nonexclusive license for a library that already does exactly what they need and is available right now.

If they demand as a condition of continued employment that you give them a copy, you could release it under the GPL, and then offer them a commercial license.  Dual licensing is actually pretty common these days, for just this kind of situation.  This lets them get started using the GPL'ed version, and then the commercial license lets them release the product without having to release the source as well.

You need to consult an attorney on this, and the sooner the better.  DO NOT take any action until and unless you have done so.

PERSONALLY, I'd suggest you think long and hard about whether you really want to work for them.  It sounds as though they have some ethics problems.

Comment: "That library is YOUR property." - given the OP said it was based on work performed during their PhD, even that isn't certain.

Comment: Good point. The school may have some claim on it. You need to have your lawyer talk to their lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

Open sourcing your software in this case would gain you nothing. It would remove their incentive to give you sizable compensation/equity. And it would even turn away potential investors. If they're not willing to negotiate in good faith, then you need to walk away. There is absolutely nothing to be gained from negotiating with someone who negotiates in bad faith. Either they're trying to take advantage of you, or they're not really interested in the first place.

In the meantime, I'd suggest you watch some of the videos on youtube by YCombinator. Those guys usually give good advice for technical co-founders (or first technical employees). For instance, they have this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcfVjd_oV1I) on "How To NOT Get Screwed As A Software Engineer".

I'd suggest you read [The Partnership Charter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0738208981) by David Gage. This book will teach you how to bring up all the difficult conversations **before** you go into partnership with someone.

And I'd suggest you read this book on assertiveness training: [When I Say No, I Feel Guilty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553263900) by Manuel J. Smith. This book is best read backwards. Read the transcripts at the end first, then read the beginning of the book. Also, don't let the title mislead you. Before you make a decision on that book, I'd suggest you read its customer reviews on Amazon.